# Google Analytics Goal Tracking - visitor leaves then comes back

Tags: google-analytics

Question about goal tracking.
I have an application that I can track from Step 1 to Step 10, and the user submits data on step 11.
Pretty standard form.
We then intake the application, evaluate, then send the user and email to log back in and accept our terms and purchase the product, which are steps 12-15.

If I set up a goal funnel, will analytics know the users has come back and completed steps 12-15?
Or do I basically lose all tracking after step 11?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about reporting and goal configuration and not about coding. Please repost to Webmasters.

Comment: @nyuen seems like it's properly tagged with _google-analytics_ tag though, let's leave it open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some limitations in GA that could be a bit troublesome:

- **30-min session window**: if user comes back later, new session is initiated.
- **multiple browsers/devices**: if finishing the last 3 steps after receiving your email is done on different laptop/mobile device, the user will have different ClientID and so you won't be able to stitch the data together (in GA reporting interface).

There are many more aspects to it - but if the two limitations listed above doesn't seem like relevant, then the implementation shouldn't be tat difficult. For more technical details, I'd consider using [MeasurementProtocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) (fancy name for server-side tracking).